# Is it possible to generate Q classes by gradle (Kotlin-DSL) for Kotlin MongoDB Documents?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, querydsl, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a project with Maven, Kotlin, QueryDSL, Spring Boot and MongoDB. It works quite well but I thought that migrating to Gradle could speed up building it. Everything was good before I began moving module with QueryDSL. It turned up that I can not generate Q-classes for Kotlin  classes annotated with @Document.
So is there a way to solve it?
Document example (placed /src/main/kotlin/com/company, in kotlin directory):

```
package ...
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document

@Document(collection = "myDocument")
data class MyDocument(
        val smth: String
)
```

maven (piece that responsible for generating)

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Werror</arg>
                        </args>
                        <annotationProcessors>
                            org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor
                        </annotationProcessors>
                        <compilerPlugins>
                            <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        </compilerPlugins>
                    </configuration>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceDirs>
                                    <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                    <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                                </sourceDirs>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>kapt</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>kapt</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceDirs>
                                    <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                    <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                                </sourceDirs>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test-compile</id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceDirs>
                                    <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                </sourceDirs>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

For gradle+kotlin AFAIU we have to use kapt to generate Q-classes in this way

```
kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa")
```

but it does not work for me, my new build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinSourceSet
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.0.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.50"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version "1.3.21"
}

apply(plugin = "kotlin")
apply(plugin = "kotlin-kapt")
apply(plugin = "kotlin-jpa")
apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")


group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa")
    implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt")

    kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa")
    kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    kapt("org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:2.2.0.RELEASE")


    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}

//sourceSets { main["kotlin"].srcDirs += [generated] }
//val querydslSrcDir = "src/main/generated"

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

In maven I can set precisely annotation processor (org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor) but in gradle I can not figure out how to achieve it.

Comment: May I ask if and how you fixed this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You should add `implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb")` and `kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt")` in `dependencies` section.

Then add the following after `dependencies` section.

```
kapt {
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor")
}
```

Also, don't forget to remove those JPA dependencies as well.

[This is a working example i created.](https://github.com/kekhuay/nextershop-installation-service/tree/475e3e47b6adbe7785b786f82a64acd472f92ff1)

Comment: Thank you so much sir, after I tried 6 or 7 different StackoverFlow solutions and felt like giving up many times, it was your simple solution that saved me. you are my superman !